# If statement to compare character length of variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have two variables: `$value1` and `$value2`.

I want to compare the character length of the variables. If `$value1` is greater in character length than `$value2`, then do something.

How can I write this if-statement in good practice?

Comment: Check out [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strlen does not work for multi byte strings. utf8 is pretty much the most used encoding in the WWW.

Better use [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-strlen.php) instead:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$value1 = 'ö';
$value2 = 'o';
if (mb_strlen($value1) > mb_strlen($value2)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) for this:

```
if (strlen($value1) > strlen($value2)) {
    // do things
} else {
    // do other things
}
```

Comment: [`Indeed`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531526/if-statement-to-compare-character-length-of-variables-in-php#comment41689387_26531526), said as a comment. Doing a conditional's easy.

Comment: Uhms, I didn't see it @Fred-ii- . Feel free to post as an answer and I will remove the answer.

Comment: @fedorqui Why should you remove it? This is a complete answer compared to the comment which was only a comment hinting at the solution.

Comment: I didn't want to post an answer for it. I feel that answers shouldn't be posted for questions like this, unless OP has existing problems with code he/she tried. I'm sure that if I had done that, some of my peers would have most likely downvoted me.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson It's a simple conditional statement, something that is basic. Googling it would have given you many many options for solutions. I don't think this question is a good one, since you haven't provided any effort as far as code goes. There was even a solution/example in that link I gave you.

Comment: Well, [so] is full of obvious questions and answers. If it happens to have been already asked, then let's mark it as duplicate; otherwise, I do not see the harm of answering it. It adds knowledge to the site.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with string enconding I would suggest you to have a look at [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function (you will need [mb_string extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php))

```
if (mb_strlen($value1) > mb_strlen($value2))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Someone posted this just minutes before you, but thank you regardless, upvote!